# MapReduce to count occurrences of pairs

Tags: algorithm, azure, hadoop, mapreduce, azure-hdinsight

I am new to MapReduce and would like your opinion on the best MapReduce approach for the following task.

I have a single large document in the format

```
1 2 3
2
2 3 4 5
```

Each line has a list of numbers. I want to list each possible (pair) combination of numbers in any line. And I want the number of lines containing each given pair.

The result will be like

```
element1 element2 occurrences
1        1        1
1        2        1
1        3        1
2        2        3
2        3        2
3        3        2
3        4        1
3        5        1
```

There are about 2M lines in the documents, and about 1.5M different numbers. And there will be about 2.5G different pairs of numbers to be counted.

The stright forward pseudo code is like:
Invoke map for each line in the document

```
Map(int lineId, list<int> elements)
{
  for each pair of integers in elements
    emit(pair, 1)
}

Reduce((int, int) pair, list<int> counts)
{
  return sum(counts)
}
```

But this approach will require 2M mappers and 2.5G reducers. Is this a plausible way to go?
Planning on trying Hadoop on Azure.

Comment: What is "G" for a unit? Normally you would have #of files as number of mappers and a single reducer.

Comment: M = 10^6. G = 10^9. So I will have 2,000,000 mappers and 2,500,000,000 reducers if I use the listed pseudo code.

Comment: What? Do you think it will spawn a mapper for each record? It will launch a Mapper for each 64mib chunk, depending on your blocksize possible larger. You can set the number of reducers manually, you should assign a reducer for roughly 1gb of data. I don't see 2mio mappers in your case.

Comment: Since I only have one file, I will have 1 mapper according to you. (Or maybe 1 mapper per 64MB input data). This mapper should scan all the lines and find pairs of elements in each line. But what about the reducer? Should I have 1 reducer role/worker/task that is invoked 2,5*10^9 times - one for each unique pair, and should it count and output the number of occurrences for each unique pair (2,5*10^9 times), or...? (I am just trying to get the right approach for my MapReduce)

Comment: Down voting because not enough work has been done before posting the query.

Comment: @user628904 since I don't know, how large your input file is, and how it is split into blocks I can't predict how many mappers will run. Actually this must be closed, because it is no real question.

Comment: I thought that there would be one mapper per input line. But I see now that one mapper will handle many lines on the hadoop framework. Likewise I thought that there would be one reducer for each map-output, but that is also neither the case. One (by default) reducer will handle all the key-value sets from the mappers. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But this approach will require 2M mappers and 2.5G reducers. Is this a plausible way to go? Planning on trying Hadoop on Azure.

This assumption is not correct.

The number of mappers for the [FileInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html) is equal to the number of Input Splits. An Input Split can map to a block in HDFS, which is defaulted to 64MB. So, if the input file is 1024 MB, then 16 map tasks will be launched.

The number of reducers is configurable using the [mapred.reduce.tasks](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.2/mapred-default.html) parameter which is defaulted to 1. Also, note that a [combiner](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html) can be used to make the job complete faster.

Would suggest to go through the [Hadoop - The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021773.do) for better understanding of MapReduce and Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

In short, and I'm no expert, but I would do exactly that.
@Thomas Jungblut's point is important - a mapper will fire for each block of each file (size is configurable, and up to a maximum) so you won't have as many mappers as you think, besides - the point of using a platform like Hadoop, to some degree, is to let it figure it out. your logic is correct.